# Paste a Formula to only add 1 to the formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Hi i have a Column of formulas and i would like to be able to copy them and paste them anywhere in my worksheet and all the formulas would only increase by 1.

```
=B761
=B796
=B831 and so on.
```

I would like to copy this and be able to paste it anywhere and have the outcome below.

```
=B762
=B797
=B832 and so on.
```

Thanks

Comment: are these formulas always just a single reference to another cell?  Or are your real formulas more complicated than these?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Copy the range
2. Paste one cell below the top cell (if your range is `C1:C10`, copy `C1:C10`, then click `C2` and paste)
3. Select the newly pasted range, Right-Click -> Cut (Select `C2:C11`, right-click -> Cut)
4. Paste cells 1 cell up (select `C1`, Right-click -> Paste (NOT insert cut cells))

**EDIT**: This only works for contiguous cells.

Comment: @pnuts by the way, I never upvote my own answers, in case you were thinking that I did it

Comment: @pnuts lol I just tried it and it says I can't do it (I never thought to dare it hahaha but now we know). And I'm glad you like my website! :) feel free to stop by/subscribe anytime!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you'll like this! (but it is very similar to @joseph4tw's 'solution'). As he suggested, copy the range to one row lower (so relative formulae adjust automatically for row). Replace whatever the Column letter/s is with nothing. Copy again to wherever required and Replace `=` with `=B`. Delete first copy.